# why vercel return an error when deploying django app on it

Tags: python, django, vercel

I am endeavoring to deploy my Django application on Vercel following the method outlined in the video tutorial. However, during the build process, an error is being logged. Regrettably, I am unable to discern the cause of this error. Could someone proficient in this deployment process kindly pinpoint where I may have erred?

The Logs:

```
WARN! Due to `builds` existing in your configuration file, the Build and Development Settings defined in your Project Settings will not apply. Learn More: https://vercel.link/unused-build-settings
Installing required dependencies...
Failed to run "pip3.9 install --disable-pip-version-check --target . --upgrade -r /vercel/path0/requirements.txt"
Error: Command failed: pip3.9 install --disable-pip-version-check --target . --upgrade -r /vercel/path0/requirements.txt
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [21 lines of output]
      running egg_info
      writing psycopg2.egg-info/PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to psycopg2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
      writing top-level names to psycopg2.egg-info/top_level.txt
      
      Error: pg_config executable not found.
      
      pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.  Please add the directory
      containing pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable path with the
      option:
      
          python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...
      
      or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.
      
      If you prefer to avoid building psycopg2 from source, please install the PyPI
      'psycopg2-binary' package instead.
      
      For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
      <https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html>).
      
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
```

requirements.txt:

```
asgiref==3.8.1
beautifulsoup4==4.12.3
crispy-bootstrap5==2024.2
Django==4.2.11
django-bootstrap-v5==1.0.11
django-crispy-forms==2.1
django-tinymce==3.7.1
gunicorn==21.2.0
packaging==24.0
pillow==10.2.0
psycopg2==2.9.9
psycopg2-binary==2.9.9
soupsieve==2.5
sqlparse==0.4.4
tzdata==2024.1
```

settings.py:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', 'localhost', '.vercel.app', '.now.sh']
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / "staticfiles"
```

vercel.json:

```
{
    "version": 2,
    "builds": [
      {
        "src": "core/wsgi.py",
        "use": "@vercel/python",
        "config": { "maxLambdaSize": "15mb", "runtime": "python3.9" }
      }],
    "routes": [
      {
        "src": "/(.*)",
        "dest": "core/wsgi.py"
      }
    ]
  }
```

build_files.sh:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt

python3.9 manage.py collectstatic --noinput
```